# Adding a class in scala and play2

Tags: scala, playframework

Where do I put a new class file, and how do I import it in the Application controller?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

New classes for both the Java and Scala versions of Play 2 are meant to be a part of the `app/models/` package. And the import would simply be `import models.className`.

You should check out the tutorial they have listed on the PlayFramework site, it should be of use to you, and can be found here: http://www.playframework.org/documentation/2.0.1/ScalaTodoList